# MongoDB slow query over an empty collection that has a watch

Tags: mongodb

I'm relatively new in MongoDB.

I have a single MongoDB instance in replica set in order to use 'watch'. We are currently watching on 'insert' events over the 'removeCollection' collection, the point is this collection is always empty (so noone is inserting anything there right now).

But the log is suddenly showing the below "slow query" message dozens of times. When this happens, the cpu consumption increases a 20%.

```
{
   "t":{
      "$date":"2022-11-16T09:15:45.836+00:00"
   },
   "s":"I",
   "c":"COMMAND",
   "id":51803,
   "ctx":"conn522936",
   "msg":"Slow query",
   "attr":{
      "type":"command",
      "ns":"ventusproxy1.removeCollection",
      "command":{
         "getMore":2257121337268066828,
         "collection":"removeCollection",
         "batchSize":2147483647,
         "$db":"ventusproxy1",
         "$clusterTime":{
            "clusterTime":{
               "$timestamp":{
                  "t":1668590144,
                  "i":14391
               }
            },
            "signature":{
               "hash":{
                  "$binary":{
                     "base64":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
                     "subType":"0"
                  }
               },
               "keyId":0
            }
         },
         "lsid":{
            "id":{
               "$uuid":"47ffbf37-2a66-4b6f-bfb0-57f0e83075e2"
            }
         },
         "$readPreference":{
            "mode":"primaryPreferred"
         }
      },
      "originatingCommand":{
         "aggregate":"removeCollection",
         "pipeline":[
            {
               "$changeStream":{
                  
               }
            },
            {
               "$match":{
                  "operationType":"insert"
               }
            }
         ],
         "cursor":{
            "batchSize":2147483647
         },
         "$db":"ventusproxy1",
         "$clusterTime":{
            "clusterTime":{
               "$timestamp":{
                  "t":1668590004,
                  "i":1046
               }
            },
            "signature":{
               "hash":{
                  "$binary":{
                     "base64":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
                     "subType":"0"
                  }
               },
               "keyId":0
            }
         },
         "lsid":{
            "id":{
               "$uuid":"47ffbf37-2a66-4b6f-bfb0-57f0e83075e2"
            }
         },
         "$readPreference":{
            "mode":"primaryPreferred"
         }
      },
      "planSummary":"COLLSCAN",
      "cursorid":2257121337268066828,
      "keysExamined":0,
      "docsExamined":17228,
      "numYields":13243,
      "nreturned":0,
      "queryHash":"8D9BAD8C",
      "reslen":319,
      "locks":{
         "FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{
            "acquireCount":{
               "r":13244
            }
         },
         "Global":{
            "acquireCount":{
               "r":13244
            }
         },
         "Mutex":{
            "acquireCount":{
               "r":1
            }
         }
      },
      "readConcern":{
         "level":"majority"
      },
      "writeConcern":{
         "w":"majority",
         "wtimeout":0,
         "provenance":"implicitDefault"
      },
      "storage":{
         "data":{
            "bytesRead":89
         }
      },
      "remote":"10.1.0.7:36266",
      "protocol":"op_msg",
      "durationMillis":210
   }
}
```

I have searched trying to find a reason for that ... no luck. And I honestly don't know where to start. I would really appreciated if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks,

Joan.

Comment: What's the main concern here, that entries like these are showing up in the log file? Also, can you confirm that there are writes happening for _other_ collections?

Comment: The main concern is that these slow queries, when they are performed, are consuming a 20% cpu. And yes, there are writes on other collections, around 1.000 writes/second. The point I don't understand is that 'removeCollection' collection you see in the log is always empty, has no activity.